# Content-Based Filtering for Tagged Posts

Tags: probability, recommendation-engine, naivebayes, imbalanced-data, document-classification

## Context

### Goal

Based on a user's previous `Post` `Reactions` (Documents & Classes) (`FavLike`, `Fav`, `Like`, `Dislike`, `None`) (`FavLike` to keep classes mutually exclusive; `FavDislike` is possible, but, for obvious reasons, I don't consider it),
I want to sort a batch of new `Posts` based on each `Reaction` probability, and, in the future, maybe also on a *combined* score based on those probabilities.

For that, I'm currently using Multinomial Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression.

### Data & Evaluation

Firstly, there's the `RawData`:

```py
RawData = {
  # <Category>: {<Post>: [<Tag>]}
  None: {
    1234: ['tag', 'beach', 'photography', 'etc'],
    # [...]
  },
  # [...]
}
```

It then is processed to `Counts`:

```py
Counts = {
  # Totals = N of Documents in each category, not number of tags
  Totals: [671, 587, 1_310, 3_353, 66_994], # Actual data sample
  Tags: {
    'tag': [0, 0, 0, 4, 41],
    'photography': [601, 507, 1_080, 2_552, 56_711],
    'etc': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    # [...]
  }
}
```

After that, it is preprocessed into `Bayes` (using log-probabilities to save up on computation during evaluation; also using Laplace smoothing):

```py
Bayes = {
  Priors: [−1.59905, −1.61782, −1.48773, −1.20228, −0.06781],
  Tags: {
    'tag': [−1.69897, −1.69897, −1.69897, -1, −0.075720],
    # [...]
  }
}
```

Then, after evaluating a `Post`, the log-probabilities go through a Standard Scaler and Logistic Regressor to get some actual probabilities.

### Things To Consider

- A `Post` is a set of `Tags` (Events)

  - `Tag` order doesn't matter
  - `Tag` either is in a `Post`, or it isn't
  - The number of `Tags` in a `Post` is variable
- `Tags` may imply another (insignificant problem, though)

  - 'red_shirt' implies 'shirt'
- Space is limited: After processing the `Raw Data`, only `Counts` is used, `Bayes` is calculated on startup, and when the user reacts to a new `Post`, its `Tags` are added to `Count` and updated on `Bayes`

### Where problems arise

- `Reaction` classes are severely imbalanced

  - `None` outnumbers all the others combined (`None` count is 67k, while the others together crack 4k)
- `Tags` are really sparse

  - While some `Tags` have thousands of occurrences, the majority only have a handful, having 0 counts for all but 1 or 2 `Reaction` classes
- `Posts` with lots of `Tags` will get really low log-probabilities

  - The mean for each `Reaction`: [-307.23473004, -314.77733785, -270.50181329, -206.64016692, -8.65777954]
  - And their standard deviation: [150.89012448, 154.35610454, 134.04458405, 101.16143351, 6.68529216]
  - Sorting `Posts` that way will just essentially sort on the number of `Tags`
  - This can be mitigated if we relativise values of the log-probs (I did this with Logistic Regression)
- Even with Logistic Regression, the final probabilities are still too close to the priors of each category

### Previous Iterations

The things I described is where I'm currently at, but I've had one previous attempt that worked more or less decently:

I merged the categories into just two, one positive, one negative:

- `Positive` = 3 * `FavLike` + 2 * `Fav` + 1 * `Like`
- `Negative` = 1 * `Dislike` (At the time, I didn't have access to the `None` `Posts`)

Based on the `Reaction` of a `Post`, I added x times more to each `Tag`'s count.

Then, to evaluate, I just subtracted the log-probabilities of `Positive` and `Negative`.

## Actual Question

Given all that, how can I improve the `Reaction` prediction of my Recommender System, such that I may sort them on each category?

## Final Notes

If it still fits with my restrictions (See `Things To Consider`), I may consider switching from Naive Bayes entirely, but I prefer to still utilise some of my currently existing work.

I'm currently looking into Complement Naive Bayes, so I'm already aware of that possibility.

I'm a programmer by trade, so I'd appreciate for tips on how to implement your suggestions with code, and please limit the mathematics.
(I'm using JavaScript (Yes, really...), but I'm familiar with several languages: Python, Rust, C#, Java, Go, C, C++ etc)